# Variable precision in d3.format

Tags: javascript, svg, format, d3.js

I'm using d3.format("s") with d3.svg.axis.tickFormat to nicely format the tick labels with SI units (from the International System of Units).  It works beautifully for the most part, except for certain values that run into a rounding error and return a ton of decimal places (1400, for example, as 1400 * 0.001 = 1.4000000000000001).

To get around this I can specify a precision, such as d3.format(".2s") but this forces 2 significant digits in cases where 1 would be better.  For example, if I have ticks [5000, 10000, 15000] I would now see [5.0k, 10k, 15k].  Originally when I didn't specify precision at all I got [5k, 10k, 15k].

I'm wondering if it's possible to specify a maximum precision such that it will only get applied when the number of significant digits exceeds the number specified?  So 5000 would be 5k and not 5.0k.

Answer (score 3):

While 1400 * .001 is 1.4000000000000001, 1400 / 1000 is 1.4; multiplying an integer by a negative power of ten (such as .001) may introduce rounding error, but it appears that dividing an integer by a power of ten (such as 1000) does not. Or at least, it's less likely? I've implemented a tentative fix in the fix-si-format-rounding branch. It's strictly backwards-incompatible, but since the `d3.formatPrefix` function is undocumented, I think it'd be safe to include in the next patch release.

Edit: This fix was released in version 2.9.2.

Comment: Interesting that those two operations produce different results.  I wouldn't have guessed that.  I'll keep my eyes peeled for this fix in the next patch.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by placing an if/else statement in an anonymous function where you would output the text string. Within that if/else you can satisfy **any condition** that you want and create a **function that parses your value**. Here is an example:

```js
var w = 30, h = 300;
var data = [
  {'point':1, 'value':100.005},
  {'point':2, 'value':20.010},
  {'point':3, 'value':1000},
  {'point':4, 'value':5000.099},
  {'point':5, 'value':6000.934},
  {'point':6, 'value':9000.888},
  {'point':7, 'value':500.22},
  {'point':8, 'value':5.123},
  {'point':9, 'value':50.022},
  {'point':10, 'value':7000.999}
];
var chart = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr('class', 'chart')
  .attr("width", w * data.length - 1)
  .attr("height", h);

chart.selectAll('text')
  .data(data)
.enter().append('text')
  .attr('x', function(d, i) { return x(i); })
  .attr('y', function(d) { return h - y(d.value); })
  .attr('dx', '0.75em')
  .attr('dy', '-0.3em')
  .attr('text-anchor', 'start')
  .text(function(d) { 
    if(d.value > 5000) {
      // Define your formatting function to return SI units
      var si = d3.format('s');
      return String(si(d.value));
    } else {
      // Otherwise round to the nearest integer
      return String(d3.round(d.value, 0));
    }
  });
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I'm using the d3.svg.axis helper so the values I'm formatting are tick values, not data values. The formatting is done internally as the tick labels are generated. I could wrap the function returned from d3.format in my own function to intercept the values but re-parsing the string returned from the SI formatter doesn't feel too clean.  I was wondering there might be something built into the formatter to support this without coding it myself.

Comment: Ahh right. My code is for the data labels, not tick labels. Hope I didn't lead you down the wrong path. Could you do something similar, but with the tick labeling functions (ie. pass in an anonymous func to them)?